# Python Selenium scrape of javascript array

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

Using Python/Selenium, I'm able to get several pages deep into a password protected website I use for work.

However, I've hit a wall with a JavaScript array from which I need to open a drop-down and select the first option.

Here is the location on the page:
[image]

Copy JS Path: `document.querySelector("#miFavorite")`

Copy XPATH: `//*[@id="miFavorite"]`

And this is the JS:

[image]

XPATH: `//*[@id="Form1"]/script[3]/text()`

How can I select `menuItem[0]`?

EDIT: adding the other page of the code:

[image]

XPATH: `/html/body/form/div[3]/ul/li[1]/a`

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just:

```
item = driver.execute_script('return menuItem[0]`)
```

Comment: Thank you. That didn't cause an error, so must be a step in the right direction. But it also did not do anything (and I removed the `item =` part). Looking back at the code for this page, there are other instances of `menuItem[0]`. How can I single out just this one? Also, when set equal to `item`, what's the next step. (As is surely obvious, this is my first time scraping.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35684454)

Comment: @xdeepakv I see that I forgot the question mark, but otherwise did I not do as you suggest?

Comment: If that didn't work you probably have to parse the doMenuClick with regex and execute_script that

Comment: @pguardiario I'm not sure what that means. I've been reading the docs, this site, "tutorial" sites, and watching videos in hopes of find information that addresses this problem I'm having. I even bought a packt book that never gets beyond the basics. Do you know where I can find instructional information that explains this?

Comment: Sorry, it's cut off in your screenshot but there's a doMenuClick function that's the javascript action for that menuitem, so you would parse it with regex and then execute that it with driver.execute_script. If you don't know what regex is this will become a project but maybe you can post that part as a regex question.